# BizTalk WCF SQL Adapter Message Transaction Setting

Tags: transactions, adapter, biztalk, msdtc

I'm working on a BizTalk solution where by all transactions are long running calling the WCF SQL Adapter. In some instances we perform updates and we have `useAmbientTransaction` set to True. It's my understanding that the means we are using MSDTC. The issue we have is that our technical team don't like the idea of opening the number of ports in the firewall to enable MSDTC as apparently they are quite numerous.

The thing is, if we set the Use Transaction on the Message Tab to unchecked the transactions appear to work even though `useAmbientTransaction` on the bindings to true and all the MSDTC ports are still closed. I haven't been able to find any blogs or references to this so I'm hoping someone could explain how this could be the case.

To be clear, we are not performing multiple SQL calls as part of a single transaction. It's only one SQL call per request. The SQL server is on a different environment from the BizTalk server.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason as to why there is a firewall between your BizTalk server and the DB server? There are potentially many, but within organizations it happens that there is actually no firewall at all between **internal** servers.

Nevertheless, assuming there is a firewall:
I believe the `UseAmbientTransaction` setting is used for two things:

1. Specifies whether the SQL adapter performs the operations using the transactional context provided by the caller. Default is true, which means that the adapter always performs the operations in a transactional context. If there are other resources participating in the transaction, and SQL Server also joins the transaction, the transaction gets elevated to an MSDTC transaction.

   Also see [Working with BizTalk Adapter for SQL Server Binding Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787981.aspx)
2. Indicating that there is a different polling mechanism involved: if you set `UseAmbientTransaction` to 'True', the `PollingDataAvailableStatement` will be executed for each poll. Disabling it (set to False), and only the `PollingStatement` will be executed.